# come across someone in a market

Tags: sentence-construction

When I go to a crowded place like a supermarket, it is possible to almost hit someone sometimes while seeing goods and moving forwards.

How to describe this situation idiomatically? Not sure if *come across* is the correct phrasal verb.

> It is easy to come across someone in a crowded market.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence

> *It is easy **to come across** someone in a crowded market*

is semantically incorrect if you want it to say that

> *It's easy **to hit someone with a shopping cart** in a crowded market.*

Sometimes you have to be specific when you make such statements. Ambiguous statements like these, for example:

> *It's easy **[to bump into someone](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/bump-into-sb)** in a crowded market*
>   *It's easy **[to run into someone](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/run-into)** in a crowded market*

could mean either **to hit someone with a shopping cart** or **to crash into someone while walking** or else **to unexpectedly meet someone you know (of)**, a friend or a TV celebrity, for example.

Once when flying EVA Air from Taiwan to LA, I **ran into** CNN reporter Mike Chinoy (we were flying business class; I was unexpectedly bumped up from economy class; he or CNN had paid for his business class). I just happened to be sitting across the aisle from him, but he looked like an old EFL colleague of mine from Tokyo, so I didn't recognize him. I thought he was my old colleague. He noticed my stare and introduced himself. I was embarrassed. I didn't **collide** with Mr Chinoy, but I did **bump/run into him**. And even though **to come across someone** means **[to meet someone by chance](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/come-across)**, I wouldn't say it to describe bumping into Mr Chinoy.

Answer (score 2):

You could say it is easy to *bump into* someone in a crowded market.

Edit:

To distinguish this from the other meaning of *bump into* which is to encounter someone, the sentence can be *it is easy to **physically** bump into someone in a crowded market*.

Comment: The problem with this is that "to bump into" has at least two distinct meanings: one is _to hit_ (as with a grocery cart) & the other is _[to unexpectedly meet](http://rdd.me/nde1k4oy)_ (as when you see purely by chance someone you know in the middle of Tokyo, NYC, or LA).

Comment: Bill, that's a good point. It still has the meaning of physically bumping into someone so, it's correct usage. That considered, it could be clarified by saying *it is easy to physically bump into someone in a crowded market*.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The problem isn't that it doesn't mean what the OP wants to say, just that it's ambiguous & needs to be disambiguated in this case.

Answer (score 1):

To "come across someone" is an idiom, meaning that you have unexpectedly encountered a person who you know or are looking for.  Similarly, "run into" and "bump into" are often used idiomatically to mean only that you encountered a person, not that there was actual physical contact.  So there is a risk of misinterpretation if you say "it is easy to *run / bump into* someone in a crowded market."

You could use a word or phrase that is more specifically geared toward physical contact, such as "jostle" or "elbow" (as a verb) or "bump" (without "into").

Alternatively, since the point of your original sentence is that you *almost* make contact but don't, you might make your statement a bit differently:

> You have to be careful not to *jostle* / *elbow* / *bump* people in a crowded market.